# Excel: Difference in hours between duplicates

Tags: excel

I am having a problem, hope you can help.

I need to have the differente in hours between duplicates. Example:

```
Date Time           |   SESSION_ID  |  Column I need

24/01/2020 10:00    |   100         |  NaN

24/01/2020 11:00    |   100         |  1

14/03/2020 12:00    |   290         |  NaN

16/03/2020 13:00    |   254         |  NaN

16/03/2020 14:00    |   100         |  1251
```

In `session_ID` column, there are 3 duplicates with value `100`.

I need to know the difference in hours between those sessions, which would be 1 hour between the first and the second, and 1 251 hours between the second and the third.

Does anyone has any type of clue on how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula XLOOKUP, put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B2),A2-XLOOKUP(B2,$B$1:B1,$A$1:A1,,0,-1),"NaN")
```

Then format the column: `[h]`

[image: ![enter image description here]

If not then use INDEX/AGGREGATE in its place:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B2),A2-INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($B$1:B1)/($B$1:B1=B2),1)),"NaN")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]